# datapicker in typescript won't see d.ts mapping

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui-datepicker

when using the JQueryUI to have a datapicker I referenced the included the JQueryUI.js file in a script tag and then had the code below in the "onLoad" function.

```
$(function () {
    // initialize the JQuery datepicker to use our standard dd MMM yyyy format
    let x = $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy"
    });
});
```

Now that I'm moving to typescript, I have downloaded the typescript mappings file and included it in the typings folder just like the JQuery.d.ts but the project won't compile because it says ".datepicker does not exist in JQuery"

Any thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: In the end, I created my own datepicker control using a html5 canvas element.  I never did find out the problem with the jQuery typeings

Answer (score 0):

Since the `datepicker()` method is not part of jQuery, the definition won't contain it. Try adding the definition for jQuery UI too!

Typings:

```
typings install dt~jqueryui --save --global
```

Tsd:

```
tsd install jqueryui --save
```

Or the file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jqueryui

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I guess I forgot to mention that I actually do have the typed file for the UI as well.  jqueryui.d.ts and it is installed in exactly the same was as the jquery.d.ts.  That is essentially my quandary, why doesn't the compiler see that there is the jqueryui.d.ts file?

Comment: What typing manager are you using? Both tsd (`tsd.d.ts`) and typings (`index.d.ts`) create a "unified" definition file in your typings folder with all your installed typings included. You should reference that definition file using the ref comment, like `/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />` in the beginning of your file.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 I'm not sure what manager it is using.  Furthermore it is unclear how the various version of Typescript managers integrate into other products.